# Rotary Encoder - Unexpected output

Tags: microcontroller, encoder

I'm seeing unexpected data on the A & B outputs of my ALPS incremental rotary encoder. The A & B pins are are attached to a microcontroller with pull-ups enabled and the centre pin is ground The pulses are aligned on their rising or falling edges rather than being 90 deg out of phase as I expected (and documented everywhere). Attached are two capture screenshots, one for clockwise the other anticlockwise rotation. Am I missing something?

[image: Clockwise]

[image: Anticlockwise]

Comment: You are missing the all-important link to the data sheet.

Comment: Looks like channel 1 is getting ANDed with channel 2. If it were a simple short, I’d expect both would rise or fall together, so I think the fault is more complex. If you have other pins available on the MCU, try the same setup on different pins; if it’s the same, try another encoder.

Comment: Link to [datasheet] (https://docs.rs-online.com/8546/0900766b810a5d53.pdf)

Comment: I've tried connecting to other pins on the microcontroller, same output. Only have the one encoder to hand.

Comment: Which specfic part number you have, and does it match to what you ordered? Are you sure it is not a wrong part with absolute output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have, most likely, connected pin A or B to ground instead of C.

[image]

*Figure 1. Encoder pinout. (Click to enlarge.)*

[image]

*Figure 2. (1) Encoder ABC. (2) Push-button pins.*

Now that C is the centre pin.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu2k9E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 3. In (a) 'A' requires both switches to close before it will pull low. This will occur 25% of the time. 'B' just requires SW2 to be closed to pull low. This will occur 50% of the time.*

Comment: Nice catch! +1.

Comment: Genius! - That's exactly what it was